# How to get the viewed items from a p-dataTable as an object

Tags: angular, primeng

i am using PrimeNG (1.0.0-beta.7) based on Angular 2 (2.0.0-rc.2).

Have anyone a idea how i can get the viewed items from a p-dataTable as an object in my Component?

I need this to fire a REST Call to a Webservice with only the visible elements and not for all elements.

Thanks, Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it :)

Solution is:

In the returned object is a "dataToRender" with the elements.

Cheers Chris